# How do I keep the other columns of my pandas dataframe while appling a function to two columns in

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to change de type of two columns at the same time. But when I do it, my dataframe remains with the only two columns changed. How can I avoid dropping the "c" column in my example?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2020-01-01', '2019-01-01'],
                  'b': ['1999-01-01', '2000-01-01'],
                  'c': ['dsdsd', 'asas']})

df = df[['a','b']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the value again to those columns and it will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2020-01-01', '2019-01-01'],
                  'b': ['1999-01-01', '2000-01-01'],
                  'c': ['dsdsd', 'asas']})

df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a','b']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Pandas don't support inplace apply so I think the above way is the shortest way to achive that

Comment: No problem! @JessicaVoigt